# A project in Lean which involves "programming"

Tags: lean4

all,

I have a project in Lean which turns out to involve some features which might better be called programming. So, for that part of the project, I was thinking I would treat Lean like it is Python in a few ways. For this I was hoping to have dynamic data types. Could anyone help me by writing out the following examples, translating from pseudocode to Lean? The more explicit the better.

Thanks very much!

**INT: Dynamic natural number type**

- INT a = 1
- a = a + 1
- a = 3

**STRING: a dynamic string type**

- STRING s = "a"
- s = "b" %Now s is set to "b"

**LIST[X]: a dynamic list of type X**

- l : LIST[STRING] = ["a","b", "c"]
- l[0] = "k" %resets "a" to "k". The new list is ["k", "b", "c"]
- l.delete(1) %deletes "b". The new list is ["k", "c"]
- l.add("b", 2) %new list is ["k", "c", "b"]

**STRUCTURE: a dynamic class-ish type**

- Can introduce any number of pieces of associated types like strings, lists of strings, etc.
- Can be initiated by specifying associated types
- Some associated types are default
- Accessing and modifying associated types
- Demanding proofs of various properties during initiation

**STRUCTURE whose constituents have a product**

- S : STRUCTURE
- s1 : S
- s2 : S
- a : s1
- b : s2
- #check (a, b)

s1 x s2

- a : s1 x s2
- #check pi1(a)

s1

- #check pi2(a)

s2

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: I think your questions are about how do you accomplish procedural programming (as say in Python) in a purely functional language.  I would look at both [this section of Functional Programming in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/getting-to-know/conveniences.html) and [this section](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/do.html) of the Lean 4 manual.

Comment: You need to explain your use case. Otherwise, the answer for the first example is `def a := 3`.  ;) However, I think you have an application such as a “for loop” in mind where you change the value of `a` dynamically. The usual functional programming approaches are [recursion](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/getting-to-know/datatypes-and-patterns.html#recursive-functions) and `fold`. But Lean 4’s `do` notation also supports [(pretty slick) notation](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/do.html#iteration) similar to that of procedural languages like Python.

Comment: I gave the wrong section in Functional programming in Lean.  But honestly, I would just skim through all the currently written chapters.

Comment: @JasonRute so Structure, Nat, and String are dynamic in nature?

Comment: @JasonRute Also List would be nice

Comment: By dynamic, I thought you meant mutable, but Strings in Python are not. Can you clarify what you mean by dynamic?

Comment: @ÖölbyGörgenöldel: Lean has static typing and you should not fight it. It ensures correctness of programs in a way that Python's dynamic typing cannot. The types you are asking for are all there already, and more, but not the dynamic everybody-do-whatever-they-like versions. If you do go the way you are asking about, you will end up implementing a mini-interpreter for a Python-like language in Lean. This will incur an unreasonable overhead in terms of performance and utility.

Comment: @DanielMGessel: here is [an explanation of dynamic typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#DYNAMIC).

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ah, thanks. I didn't interpret "dynamic data types" to mean "dynamically typed" - the given examples led me to think "dynamic" as "changeable".

Comment: My best guess is that the OP just wants to use what they know already, even if Lean offers a different solution. So the correct answer is "these are not the dynamic types you are looking for".

Comment: You are most likely missing the point of the exercise if you try to treat lean like python

Comment: @ÖölbyGörgenöldel I edited my answer with sections on polymorphism and type classes which should cover your questions on "dynamic class-ish" structures.  But I also didn't intend to write a whole Lean manual here.  I would recommend looking at the actual Lean manuals, trying to write some code for your particular use cases, and when you get stuck asking a *specific* question here (or on the Lean Zulip) detailing the exact thing you are trying to do (focusing on the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and where you are stuck).  It will be easier (and less work) for people to help you.

Answer (score 11):

First there is no reason to put quotes around "programming".  Lean 4 is a fully capable programming language with all the needed features.  But it is also a (very pure) *functional programming language* and your question conveys some confusion both of how functional languages work and even of how Python works.

Here is a crash course focusing on your questions.

### Mutability

In Python, many types (e.g. `int`, `str`, `tuple`) are *immutable*, meaning you can never change an object of that type.  In Python, when you do

```python
x = "Hello World!"
x = x.replace("Hello", "Goodbye")
```

you are not changing the string "Hello World!", but instead creating a new string in the second line and pointing that variable `x` to the new string.  If the previous string is no longer referenced (as in this example), then the Python garbage collector cleans it up.  (C and Rust are different in this regard, but we don't need to worry about that.)  Lean is very similar to Python in this regard.

```
def goodbye_world : String :=
  let x := "Hello World!" 
  let x := x.replace "Hello" "Goodbye" -- a new string with the same variable name as before
  x                                    -- the value at the end of a function is what is returned

#eval goodbye_world  -- Goodbye World!
```

### Lists and persistent data structures

In Python some types are *mutable* (changable) like `list`

```python
x = [0, 1, 2]
y = x        # x and y point to the same list
x.append(3)  # change the list
x[0] = 4     # change the list
print(y)     # [4, 0, 1, 2]
```

Since in pure functional programming all types are immutable, one has to think differently.  Consider using the immutable `tuple` in Python instead of `list`:

```python
x = (0, 1, 2)
y = x             # x and y point to the same tuple, but not for long
x = x + (3,)      # x is a new tuple (0, 1, 2, 3)
x = (0,) + x[1:]  # x is a new tuple (4, 1, 2, 3)
print(y)          # y never changed: (0, 1, 2)
```

This isn't really a problem for simple cases, but if the tuple gets too big it can lead to a lot of copying of data.

Because immutable structures are all there are in pure functional programming, functional programming tends to adopt *persistent* data structures.  These are immutable data structures where you can change a little part without having to make a copy of the whole thing.  Instead of having a list be a single block of memory, it is made up of a series of pointers (basically a linked list).  So if you change one part of the list you don't have to copy a giant block of data.  Here is a hacky version in Python, but the Lean version is cleaner:

```python
x = (1, (2, (3, None)))  # linked list
head, tail = x
y = (4, tail)  # (4, (2, (3, None)))
```

I've changed the first element of the linked list, but I've done so without copying the whole object.  `x[1]` and `y[1]` point to the same object in memory.  Lean's `List` type is built this way:

```
def example_lists : List Nat × List Nat :=
  let x := [0, 1, 2]
  let y := 4 :: x
  (x, y)   

#eval example_lists  -- ([0, 1, 2], [4, 0, 1, 2])
```

Now there is a further complexity with `List` in Lean.  Usually in Lean you want your functions to handle all possible cases.  So one can't just pop the head of a list since the list might be empty.  Lean4 has many ways to deal with this:

```
def l := [1, 2, 3]
def e := ([] : List Nat)

#eval l.head (by simp)  -- 1  (Must supply a proof that l ≠ [].)
#eval e.head _   -- No proof for _ would make this compile.
#eval l.head?    -- some 1  (Answer in an Option.)
#eval e.head?    -- none    (Answer in an Option.)
#eval l.head!    -- 1
#eval e.head!    -- 0  (Returns default value for Nat type in #eval.  
                 --     If run inside `main : IO unit` will give runtime error.)
#eval l.headD 0  -- 1
#eval e.headD 0  -- 0  (We supplied a default value.)
```

`List.head` and `List.head?` are the most principled approaches.  `List.head!` is fine for simple one-off applications but your program may crash if you make a mistake.  `List.headD` in my opinion is more likely to lead to subtle bugs than be helpful.

For more list operations, see the [Lean 4 source code](https://github.com/leanprover/lean4/tree/master/src/Init/Data/List).

So we can do:

```
def example_list : List Nat :=
  let y := [0, 1, 2]
  let y := 4 :: y.tail! -- add 4 to the front of y
  let y := y ++ y  -- concatenate y with itself
  y

#eval example_list -- [4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2]
```

Note, `List` is meant to be used as a [*stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)) and you will get better performance operating on the left of a `List` than the right side.

### Structures

Like `List`s, Lean (and most other functional languages) make it easy to work with structures in a persistent way.  Often you want to change just one element of a structure.  To do that you need to make a copy of the structure and change that element.  It would be a pain to have to re-enter all the previous information again each time.  In Lean, you just have to specify which fields are changing.

```
structure Pair where
  x : Nat
  y : Nat

def origin : Pair := {x := 0, y := 0}

#reduce origin                -- { x := 0, y := 0 }
#reduce {origin with x := 1}  -- { x := 1, y := 0 }
#reduce {origin with y := 1}  -- { x := 0, y := 1 }
```

### Polymorphism

Since Lean is statically typed it has to know the type of every variable at compile time.  Nonetheless (like almost all statically typed functional programming languages) a type in Lean can depend on another type.  For example, `List` depends on the type of the elements in the list.  Since `List` (and every other type in Lean) is immutable, your can't change it, but you can make a new list with the same variable which has a different type.  This is a common use case for `List.map`:

```
def my_list_of_strings : List String :=
  let x : List Nat := [0, 1, 2, 3] -- List Nat
  let x : List Int := x.map (fun y : Nat => -y)
  let x : List String := x.map (fun y : Int => y.repr)
  x

#eval my_list_of_strings  -- ["0", "-1", "-2", "-3"]
```

Structures also allow polymorphism in two ways shown here:

```
structure LabeledPoints (CarrierType : Type) where
  LabelType : Type
  label : CarrierType -> LabelType

def my_labeled_nat : LabeledPoints Nat := { 
  LabelType := String,
  label := fun x => x.repr
}

#check my_labeled_nat -- LabeledPoints Nat
#eval my_labeled_nat.label 0 -- "0"
```

Whether to put the type inside (e.g. `LabelType`) or outside (e.g. `CarrierType`) is largely dependent on context and use case.  (See the discussion on [*bundled*](https://leanprover-community.github.io/glossary.html#bundled-vs-unbundled) structures.)

### Type Classes

In a polymorphic setting everything you do must work for all possible types.  So I can make the following theorem.

```
theorem LabeledPoints.has_label
  (T : Type) 
  (labeled_points : LabeledPoints T) 
  (t : T): \exists l : labeled_points.LabelType, labeled_points.label = l :=
```

and because I put it in the `LabeledPoints` namespace, I can use it with "dot notation" as follows:

```
#check my_labeled_nat.has_label 0  -- Prop
```

But I can't construct this next function since not all types `T` have a string representation (like `Nat` did in the example above).

```
def mk_repr_labeled_points (T : Type) : LabeledPoints T := { 
  LabelType := String,
  label := fun x => x.repr  -- this won't work since not all types T have T.repr
}
```

Instead, to do this, one needs *type classes*.  Type classes are a way that Lean (and other functional programming languages) let you define functions, structures, and other types which only depend on a certain class of types instead of all possible types.  In this next example, the type class parameter `[Repr T]` expresses that `T` must have a representative string function (which can be accessed with `reprStr`).

```
def mk_repr_labeled_points (T : Type) [Repr T]: LabeledPoints T := { 
  LabelType := String,
  label := reprStr
}

#check mk_repr_labeled_points True  -- fails to typecheck
#check mk_repr_labeled_points Int   -- LabeledPoints Int
#eval (mk_repr_labeled_points Int).label (-1 : Int) -- "-1"
```

### Loops

The examples so far are kind of silly.  What you often want to do is keep changing a variable in a loop.  In functional programming loops are often done with recursion and you should learn it.  Here are two ways to accomplish the task of adding the squares of every number in a list:

This is the classic recursive approach.  (I could also make this *tail recursive*, but that is too advanced right now for this answer.)

```
def sum_of_squares : List Nat -> Nat
| []     => 0
| x :: t => x * x + sum_of_squares t

#eval sum_of_squares [0, 1, 2, 3]  -- 14
```

Iterating over a `List` is so common, there is a function `foldl` just for this which makes it a one-liner.

```
#eval [0, 1, 2, 3].foldl (fun x partial_sum => x * x + partial_sum) 0
```

### Advanced Lean feature: `do` notation

If you want to do real programming, you probably want to print to STDOUT and read data from a file or from STDIN.  To do this, you have to use the `IO` monad.  I don't have room to go into the details, but when you are in a `do` block of the IO monad it looks even more like procedural programming (e.g. Python).  You can do `sum_of_squares` like this:

```
def sum_of_squares_io (l : List Nat) : IO Nat := do
  let mut r := 0
  for x in l do
    r := r + x * x
  return r
```

But note that your result will be wrapped in the `IO` monad.  See The Lean 4 Manual and Functional Programming in Lean for more information.

### Advanced Lean feature: `|>.` notation

Instead of `let ... let ... let ...` often you just want to chain your functions together into a one-liner.

```
#eval "Hello World!".replace "Hello" "Goodbye"
```

but it isn't easy to add in another `.replace` here since `.replace` has arguments .  For that, Lean added the `|>.` notation (along with `|>`, and `<|`.)

```
#eval "Hello World!" |>.replace "Hello" "Goodbye" |>.replace "!" "?"
-- Goodbye World?
```

### Advanced Lean feature: In-place changes

(I could be a bit mistaken on what I write in this section.)  Unlike most other purely functional languages, Lean has support for non-persistent data structures without breaking the pure functional programming paradigm. For example, if you want to work with an `Array` or a `HashMap`, you can.  It works like this:  If you create an object at the same time that you dereference another object of the same Type, the Lean compiler will, instead of allocating new memory, just reuse the old memory.  For objects like Array, instead of making a copy of the array, it will just update the array *in-place*.  But it can be a bit tricky to get the syntax right (and unlike Rust, the Lean compiler won't help you keep track of references to be sure your only have one pointer to an array).

```
def example_array : Array Nat :=
  let a := Array.mk [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  let b := a.set! 3 10  -- makes a *copy* of a (since a is still referenced)
                        -- and modifies element in position 3
  let b := b.set! 4 11  -- modifies b *in-place*

#eval example_array -- [0, 1, 2, 10, 11]
```

### Final thoughts

Learning functional programming is not a one-day activity.  It requires a new way of thinking about coding.  Lean 4 is a wonderful language with great features and syntax choices, but it is still very different from procedural languages like Python.  Expect a learning curve.  For learning more I would recommend:

- [Functional Programming in Lean](https://leanprover.github.io/functional_programming_in_lean/) (in progress)
- [The Lean 4 Manual](https://leanprover.github.io/lean4/doc/) (in progress)
- [Theorem Proving in Lean 4](https://leanprover.github.io/theorem_proving_in_lean4/title_page.html) (The most comprehensive Lean 4 manual so far.  While it focuses on theorem proving, the sections on induction and recursion, and on structures would be especially applicable to programming.)
- A good tutorial or course for another functional language, like Haskell or Scala